# Multithreading/processing for loop not working or slower than original def

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

First off, this is my first attempt to multithreading or multiprocessing (outside of tutorials).  I am trying to speed up some initializations in my class by using multithreading or multiprocessing, not sure which one makes more sense yet.  My code goes something like this

```py
import threading

classlist = []

filelist = ['a','b','c'] #it's a list of string paths

def loadClasses(filelist):
    global classlist, filelist
    classlist = [OtherClass(i) for i in filelist]

def threadingfunc(filelist):
    t1.threading.Thread(target=loadClasses)

threadingfunc()
```

This seems to take twice as long compared to when I just run the `loadClass` function.
The `OtherClass` takes about 1.5 seconds to run but when I have about 40 files to load, it adds up.

I attempted to try the same thing with multiprocessing and it didn't seem to work at all.
As far as multiprocessing goes, I have not had any luck making anything work.  This is close to what I've used.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

classlist = []
def loadClass(file):
    classlist.append(OtherClass(file))

def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    for file in filelist:
        p.map(loadClass, file)
```

This took about the same amount of time.  So I'm not sure where to go from here.
Long story short, I have a list of files I want to load into my `OtherClass` and I'm looking for ways to speed it up.
I appreciate any help and please be nice to a nooby!

I've tried the above code chunks with multithreading and multiprocessing.  I was able to get them to work, but I saw no improvement in speed of completion.  Some methods were in fact longer.

Comment: multiprocessing has fixed overhead for starting the process, sending over the arguments to the other thread, and sending back the response.  Multithreading is only faster when at least a reasonable amount of work is done on the other thread that's more than the overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## python threads

Using threads in C++ can let you burn all cores, and finish faster.

Using threads in python is typically only of interest
for I/O bound processes like a web server.
Each thread must acquire the
[GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock#Examples)
before accomplishing any work, so applying python threads
to a compute bound job typically won't be winning.

---

## lint

```
def loadClass(file):
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asked you nicely: spell it `load_class`, please.

This is especially salient because the function
under consideration is manifestly not a class.
No need to provoke `LoadClass` double-take confusion.

---

## cores

```
    p = Pool(2)
```

It is *possible* that you're on a Pentium with two cores.
But more likely you have greater than five cores available.
You could specify a larger number, but you might prefer to
let it default to number of cores detected at runtime.

## overhead: serializing

```
    for file in filelist:
```

You mentioned that each "load" operation takes about 1500 msec.
That seems a good impedance match for this line.
I will just mention that, if each operation ran in
a mere fraction of a second, then you might consider
batching up several `file` entries in a tuple,
and send them across the pipe connection
to each child process in a batch.

## overhead: deserializing

```
        p.map(load_class, file)
```

I have no idea how big an object your load class function is appending to a central bottleneck global `list` in the parent.
Depending on the details, that one parent process can potentially spend a
lot of CPU cycles deserializing result values sent by children.

Often a good strategy will be to do a couple seconds
of computation, store a large JSON result in the filesystem,
and return either `None`, or the `Path` of the result file.
That way the parent process doesn't need to burn cycles
deserializing some giant JSON result.

## result order

It appears you don't care *when* things happen
as long as they *do* eventually happen, so you might be interested
in the several `pool.map()` variants, including
[imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered).

The detail here is that jobs may take different amounts of time.
Relaxing constraints on the order in which results are delivered
lets the multiprocessing library schedule jobs more aggressively,
keeping more core busy most of the time, even in the presence
of stragglers.

## stragglers

If you know things that the multiprocessing library does not,
you should expose such knowledge so it can schedule tasks
more sensibly.

For example, it might be the case that "long file"
implies "long time to load file".
If you bring that knowledge to the table,
then let the scheduler know about it. Given a
[Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths)
it is easy to ask for its `st_size`.
Use the `sorted` `key` argument to
order your forty files by decreasing size.
Then we load the big ones first,
and idle cores will see hardly any
straggler tasks at the end.

Comment: First off, thanks for the link to the PEP, I've never really had a reference for proper naming convention so I will take a look at that and bookmark it. 

Yeah I have 12 cores, and I've tried using more but it didn't seem to help much.  However, when I looked at my CPU usage during the multiprocessor operation, I didn't see a noticeable difference in usage.  Is that something the imap_unordered() would fix?

Comment: It's not exactly a matter of applying a quick "fix", it's more that you want to understand what you need and what the system is providing. It sounds like you have `1.5 × 40 = 60` seconds of compute to do, and you'd like your dozen cores to accomplish that in about five seconds. tl;dr: That won't happen. In the best case we could do that for 36 tasks, with each core ideally spending 4.5 seconds on it. With 40 tasks, it's guaranteed that _someone_ is going to have to spend 6 seconds on four tasks, while other cores are idle. We call those "stragglers". The imap variants relax constraints, though

Comment: Yeah I did.  I ended up getting that 1.5 second time down to 30 milliseconds.  I still have a way to go to understand how I can use this I think.  But you've given me a lot of great information to work with.